# subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ - which is group with adding

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Which of below subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ is group.
a. $\mathbb{R}$
Yes, each element has reversed element and $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition.
b. $\{a+bi:a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}$
Yes, it is also group:  reversed element for $a+bi$ is $(-a-bi)$.  Clousure under addition is obvious.

c. $\mathbb{N}$
No, lack of reversed element for $1$.

Am I ok ?

Comment: These are correct.

Comment: Correct.........FYI : The standard  term in English is "inverse" rather than "reversed".